# Template: Deduction of array size failed

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am trying to restrict the type of elements to be processed as `std::array<std::string,N>>`, but template substitution fails for N.

```
main.cpp:10:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:31:34: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'N'
     print(word.begin(),word.end());
```

My attempt is as following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>    

template<typename ForwardIterator,std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename ForwardIterator::value_type,std::array<std::string,N> >::value >::type
print(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
{
    for( auto const & arr : boost::make_iterator_range(begin,end) )
    {
        for( auto const & item : arr)
        {
            std::cout<<item<<' ';
        }
        std::cout<<'\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string,2>> word;
    word.push_back( {{"hello","Hi"}} );
    word.push_back( {{"b","bye"}} );
    print(word.begin(),word.end());
}
```

[Demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f557fdbd8f93c5f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your approach and, instead of comparing the type to an array of an unknown size (that is, the compiler can't tell what `N` wou have in mind), verify if the type itself can be deduced as an array:

```
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename A>
struct is_std_array : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_std_array<T, std::array<T,N>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename ForwardIterator>
auto print(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
    -> typename std::enable_if<
           is_std_array<std::string, typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type>::value
       >::type
{

}
```

Also, not the usage of `std::iterator_traits`.

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21bbabec454abc5d)

Answer (score 1):

(This isn't really a full answer, just an attempt to intuitively explain why the current approach doesn't work.)

It's because you're not giving it any chance to deduce `N`. The `N` appears only once in the signature, and that is to *test* for equality. This does not force the types to be equal to each other.

As a really simple example, you wouldn't expect that this code would force `T` to be `int`:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int >::type
void foo(T) {
}
```

(Also, the return type of `foo` here isn't going to be `T` or `int`, it will be a special boolean type. Again, probably not what you want.)

Ultimately, what do you want here? I guess you want to ensure that it is called only with iterators whose value type is an `std::array`

Comment: Yes you are correct `I want to ensure that it is called only with iterators whose value type is an std::array`